# How to put object to Gemfire Cache in Spring Integration DSL?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-integration, gemfile, spring-integration-dsl

I have integration flow and I want to write the entity in the flow to my Gemfire cache between the steps but I am not figuring out how to do it.

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow myFlow(CacheEntityDAL cacheDAL,Transformer t, 
MyFilter f) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("inChannel")
                .transform(t) //returns the entity
                 //I want to put to my cacheDAL.put(entity) here
                .filter(f)
                .channel("outChannel")
                .get();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To write to the Gemfire cache, you need to use a `CacheWritingMessageHandler` from the [Spring Integration Gemfire](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/gemfire.html) support.

However since this one is `one-way`, it is just for writing, there is no straight forward way to insert it in the middle of the flow. On the other you just would like to store and proceed downstream with the same payload. For this purpose I suggest to use a `PublishSubscribeChannel` with two subscribers: a mentioned `CacheWritingMessageHandler` and then rest of the flow. Something like this:

```
 return IntegrationFlows.from("inChannel")
            .transform(t) //returns the entity
            .publishSubscribeChannel(c -> c
                        .subscribe(sf -> sf
                                .handle(new CacheWritingMessageHandler(gemfireRegion()))
            .filter(f)
            .channel("outChannel")
            .get();
```

So, this way you send to the Gemfire and move to the main flow, where the next `filter()`
 is going to be as a second subscriber which won't work until a success of the first one for Gemfire.